# Is it possible for Google Data Studio get data from a Google Drive folder?

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way for Google Data Studio to get data from all files inside a Google Drive folder, like Power BI does to offline files?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no existing Connector in DS right now.

But you can write your own connector to do this:

You will need to enable Google Drive API
And make a request like that: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list

Setup and deploy Comunity Connector.

https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build

That will require knowledge of JS.